# Юнити Vector3.ClampMagnitude помогите разеснить.(c#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот Vector3.ClampMagnitude помогите пожалуйста разобраться не понимаю читал на Unity API
не понел заранее спасибо. На С#

Answer (score 1):

Функция Vector3.ClampMagnitude используется для обрезания векторов в Unity.

Возвращает копию вектора с обрезанной величиной до maxLength.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 centerPt;
    public float radius;
    void Update() {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position + movement;
        Vector3 offset = newPos - centerPt;
        transform.position = centerPt + Vector3.ClampMagnitude(offset, radius);
    }
}
```

Здесь хороший пример:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/182382/